# Как получить доступ к значениям столбца в .csv файле?

Tags: java

В задании сказано:
При работе со строками известного формата удобно пользоваться методом split(). Он делит исходную строку по символу-разделителю и возвращает массив строк. Например, чтобы разбить нашу строку, из файла по строкам нужно вызвать метод с аргументом System.lineSeparator(). Эта функция возвращает конец строки:

```
String[] lines = fileContents.split(System.lineSeparator());
```

Теперь у нас есть набор строк. Осталось разобрать каждую из них с помощью того же метода. Разделение будет проходить по символу «,»:

```
String[] lineContents = line.split(",");
```

Это позволит обращаться к конкретным значениями внутри строки.

А теперь сам вопрос:

Как это все применить в моем коде, чтоб получить доступ к значениям в файле ***xxx.csv*** для дальнейшей работы с ними (например, для получения суммы столбца sum_of_one)?:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(readFileContents("xxx.csv"));
    }

    private static String readFileContents(String filename){
    Path filePath = Paths.get(filename);
    try {
        return Files.readString(filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Невозможно прочитать файл. Возможно, файл не находится в нужной директории.");
        }
    }
}
```

***xxx.csv***

```
item_name,is_expense,quantity,sum_of_one
Коньки,TRUE,50,2000
Новогодняя ёлка,TRUE,1,100000
Ларёк с кофе,TRUE,3,50000
Аренда коньков,FALSE,1000,180
Продажа билетов,FALSE,3500,300
Продажа кофе,FALSE,2421,150
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать? вам нужно что-то типа "универсального" парсера csv-файлов?

Comment: Я должен получить доступ к колонкам, чтоб, например, получить сумму столбца

Comment: Так Вы же всё сами в вопросе написали - раз split, два split, потом 3 элемент массива lineContents

Comment: Я новичок в java и с .csv и split столкнулся впервые. Я не знаю с какой стороны к этому подойти. Поэтому и прошу показать рабочую конструкцию, чтоб все понять

Comment: Мои одногруппники пытаются применить для решения этой задачи это: HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Objects>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подходите к заданию, не продумывая решение. Ваша задача не в том, чтобы превратить  текстовый файл в переменную String. Тогда вопрос: зачем писать код, который в итоге заведет вас в тупик? Ведь изначально было понятно, что полученная переменная типа String вам не нужна и сделать с ней либо ничего нельзя , либо крайне сложно.

Для начала нам нужно преобразовать csv файл в тот вид, с которым нам будет просто работать в мире ООПешном. В моем представлении любые "табличные" данные всегда можно провести к Map, где ключ - имя столбца, значение - значение конкретной строки этой таблицы. Любой csv можно рассматривать как табличные данные: есть заголовок, есть разделитель, являющийся по факту вертикальной чертой таблицы итд. Значит нам нужно что-то , что прочитает наш csv и приведет его к Map. Это первый шаг.
Теперь мы сталкиваемся с другой проблемой: Map - отличное решение в плане универсальности использования. Но в мире строгой типизации и ООП с такими данными все еще достаточно сложно работать, посему я бы хотел иметь класс-модель, который будет принимать данные из Map, его поля будут строго типизированы, посему и с экземплярами этого класса работать будет просто. Посему следующий шаг - создание класса модели. И последнее - приведение Map к объектам этого класса.

Теперь реализация:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Parser {

    private final String delimeter;

    public Parser(String delimeter) {
        this.delimeter = delimeter;
    }

    public <T> List<T> load(InputStream is, Class<T> modelClass) throws Exception {
        final List<String> rows = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.defaultCharset()))
                .lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (rows.size() < 2) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        final String[] columnsNames = rows.remove(0).split(delimeter);
        final List<T> valuesList = new ArrayList<>(rows.size());
        for (final String v : rows) {
            final String[] value = v.split(delimeter);
            final Map<String, String> values = new HashMap(value.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) values.put(columnsNames[i], value[i]);
            final T t = modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Map.class).newInstance(values);
            valuesList.add(t);
        }
        return valuesList;
    }

}


import java.util.Map;

public class Item {

    private final String name;
    private final Boolean isExpense;
    private final Integer quantity;
    private final Integer sumOfOne;

    public Item(Map<String, String> values) {
        this.name = values.get("item_name");
        this.isExpense = Boolean.valueOf(values.get("is_expense"));
        this.quantity = Integer.valueOf(values.get("quantity"));
        this.sumOfOne = Integer.valueOf(values.get("sum_of_one"));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Boolean getIsExpense() {
        return isExpense;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public Integer getSumOfOne() {
        return sumOfOne;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" + "name=" + name + ", isExpense=" + isExpense + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", sumOfOne=" + sumOfOne + '}';
    }
    
}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Parser parser = new Parser(",");
        List <Item> items = parser.load(new FileInputStream(new File("xxx.csv")), Item.class);
        System.out.println(items);
        
        int quantitySum = items.stream().mapToInt(Item::getQuantity).sum();
        int sum = items.stream().mapToInt(Item::getSumOfOne).sum();
        System.out.println(quantitySum);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Можете пример вызова написать?

Comment: @Arty Morris уже написал в классе Main , имя путь/имя файла подставляйте вместо xxx.csv и , собственно, все

Comment: Как по мне, хороший пример как из простого преобразования списка строк в двумерный массив можно написать докторскую диссертацию :) Это ж какой оверхед по памяти на больших обьемах будет у вашего решения?

Answer (score 2):

Предложу такой вариант, если не надо лезть в ООП.

Значения для каждой строки получаются в цикле `for`. В данном примере все пары `имя=значиние` выводятся на экран.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    private static final int ITEM_NAME = 0;
    private static final int IS_EXPENSE = 1;
    private static final int QUANTITY = 2;
    private static final int SUM_OF_ONE = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String[] lines = Files
                .readString(Paths.get("file.csv"))
                .split(System.lineSeparator());

        for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

            String[] values = lines[i].split(",");

            String name = values[ITEM_NAME];
            boolean isExpense = Boolean.parseBoolean(values[IS_EXPENSE]);
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(values[QUANTITY]);
            int sumOfOne = Integer.parseInt(values[SUM_OF_ONE]);

            System.out.printf("{name=%s,isExpense=%s,quantity=%s,sumOfOne=%s\n",
                    name, isExpense, quantity, sumOfOne);
        }

    }

}
```